# What plant is this?

Tags: botany, species-identification

It was all along a fence in a downtown core in Ottawa, flowering in November.

[image]

I didn't get a better close-up of the flower itself, I had thought the leaves would be pretty important. 
[image]

Comment: where was the picture taken (Down Under November is mid-summer) and a close up of the flower is in place

Comment: My bad - I'm new at naming species and what is needed to identify a plant. I'll add a close-up. It's actually in Ottawa, so November can be a tad nippy, hence my surprise.

Comment: @SQLiteNoob Can you add the information to the question? Information given in the comments may be missed. Also, it is good if the question is complete in itself.

Comment: @SQLiteNoob This is an example of an acceptable species ID question, while your others are not acceptable. This image has a clear single plant species visible (or otherwise pointed out), and you provided information about the location and time the photo was taken. In the future, you should provide these information if you want your plant to be more easily identified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given what I can guess of the flower organization and the type of leaves I see on the first photo, they could belong to the [Ranunculaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranunculaceae) or [Rosaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosaceae) family.

#### Edit

The example of [Asteraceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteraceae) [provided by RHA](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/43571/1486) seems more likely to be close to the correct answer, although it seems to me that the leaves don't look exactly the same as the one showed in Wikipedia for [*Tanacetum parthenium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanacetum_parthenium):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanacetum_parthenium#/media/File:Tanacetum_parthenium_Blatt.JPG

Comment: Really? It looks like a composite to me

Comment: True, it could also be an Asteraceae, but the texture of the yellow part, the low number and the almost-round shape of the white petal-like parts somehow make me prefer the other hypotheses.

Comment: thanks so much for the input. It was along a fence, so I was myself trying to determine if it is a spontaneous weed or deliberately planted - it's just that there was nothing else around it that looked to be on purpose

Answer (score 9):

I disagree with @bli. I am pretty sure it is an Asteraceae, and I think I even know what species. It is *Matricaria parthenium*, also known as *Chrysanthemun parthenium* or *Tanacetum parthenium*. It is indigenous in Europe (Palearctic species) and it is also grown in gardens often. It is said to be a medicinal plant that works against fever and migraine. For more info see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanacetum_parthenium)

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer.